# Помогите составить логику

Tags: алгоритм, логика

Сразу напишу, что мне нужен не код, а описание логики.
Не могу врубиться, как правильно...

И так... Есть у нас количество чего-то (будем называть, например, деньги), и их - 100%.
И у нас есть рабочие - *n* людей. Рабочие могут смотреть и делать.)))

Есть таблица:

```
id   name   looks works

 1. People1  200   65
 2. People2  180   70
 3. People3  170   80
 4. People4  190   210
 5. People5  195   150
```

И теперь нужно узнать, сколько кому заплатить (в % от всех денег).

Платят и за просмотры, и за работу. Но явно, работа важнее просмотра. Потому думаю нужно ввести коэффициент "k" (один для всех), чтоб можно было задавать от 0 до 1 (etc. 1/2 = 0.5 (что бы значило, что робота важней за просмотр в 2 раза)).

Если бы платили только за работу - проблем нет. (Сумму всех/100)*Сумму конкретного.
А в такую задачу не могу врубиться!

Comment: конечно, если это не критично: добавьте столбик рейтингового личного коэффициента.
а теперь расчет: S=сумма всех  (looks  + works*коэффициент ) это сто процентов выплат.
у человека A=People1 (looks  + works*коэффициент )  - это искомый икс.
теперь дело пропорции: A*100/S = X (  %)
Но тут вступает куча нюансов: эта таблица только неоплаченных работ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
(look_k*K+work_k)*100/сумма0..N(look_i*K+work_i)
```

где `look_k,` `work_k` - работа конкретного персона;
K = коэффициент.

Comment: Да, все работает! Спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

Например так:

```
people_i=k*looks_i*works_i/sum(looks*works)
```